# Sed match/copy and then place in posix shell

Tags: android, linux, shell, sed, posix

So I'm trying to come up with sed to find all code that matches below between the { and the } for each variable below, however I want to exclude the search that includes any of the lines that have # (present in any part of the line). Then I want the sed script to copy the matched lines to under the "libraries {" of the expected output and then add a # At the end of the name of the first line copies for each match when copying.

Original code to find a match/copy:

```
  bundle {
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libbundlewrapper.so
  }
  #positive {
  #path /system/lib/soundfx/libpositive.so
  #}
  reverb {
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libreverbwrapper.so
  }
```

Expected output:

```
libraries {
  bundle {#
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libbundlewrapper.so
  }
  reverb {#
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libreverbwrapper.so
  }
  proxy {
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libeffectproxy.so
  }
  jdsp {
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libjamesdsp.so
  }
```

Then I want to do the same thing with below, but it's more complicated because I also need it to match and copy both of the two below (they all have "library" and "uuid", but only some have hw and sw").

Original code for match/copy:

```
  jamesdsp {
    library jdsp
    uuid f27317f4-c984-4de6-9a90-545759495bf2
  }
  sa3d {
    library proxy
    uuid  1c91fca0-664a-11e4-b8c2-0002a5d5c51b
      libsw {
        library myspace
        uuid 3462a6e0-655a-11e4-8b67-0002a5d5c51b
      }
      libhw {
        library offload
        uuid  c7a84e61-eebe-4fcc-bc53-efcb841b4625
      }
  }
  #downmix {
    #library downmix
    #uuid 93f04452-e4fe-41cc-91f9-e475b6d1d69f
  #}
 visualizer {
    library visualizer
    uuid d069d9e0-8329-11df-9168-0002a5d5c51b
  }
```

Expected output:

```
 effects {
      jamesdsp {#
        library jdsp
        uuid f27317f4-c984-4de6-9a90-545759495bf2
      }
      sa3d {#
        library proxy
        uuid  1c91fca0-664a-11e4-b8c2-0002a5d5c51b
          libsw {
            library myspace
            uuid 3462a6e0-655a-11e4-8b67-0002a5d5c51b
          }
          libhw {
            library offload
            uuid  c7a84e61-eebe-4fcc-bc53-efcb841b4625
          }
      }
     visualizer {#
        library visualizer
        uuid d069d9e0-8329-11df-9168-0002a5d5c51b
      }
      dax {
        library dax
        uuid 9d4921da-8225-4f29-aefa-6e6f69726861
      }
```

Keep in mind the above code needs to be placed under "effects {".

Comment: How did `proxy` and `jdsp` appear in the first example?

Answer (score 0):

Your source files have Tcl syntax, so if we execute them as Tcl code (with an appriopriate "unknown procedure" handler), we're good. I have your first sample as "file1.dat" and the second as "file2.dat"

```
$ cat process.tcl
rename unknown __tcl_unknown
proc unknown {cmd body} {
    puts "$cmd {#$body}"
}
lassign $argv filename prefix suffix
puts $prefix
source $filename
puts $suffix
```

Then

```
$ tclsh process.tcl file1.dat "libraries {" "  proxy {
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libeffectproxy.so
  }
  jdsp {
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libjamesdsp.so
  }"
```

```
libraries {
bundle {#
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libbundlewrapper.so
  }
reverb {#
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libreverbwrapper.so
  }
  proxy {
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libeffectproxy.so
  }
  jdsp {
    path /system/lib/soundfx/libjamesdsp.so
  }
```

and

```
$ tclsh process.tcl file2.dat "effects {" "      dax {
        library dax
        uuid 9d4921da-8225-4f29-aefa-6e6f69726861
      }"
```

```
effects {
jamesdsp {#
    library jdsp
    uuid f27317f4-c984-4de6-9a90-545759495bf2
  }
sa3d {#
    library proxy
    uuid  1c91fca0-664a-11e4-b8c2-0002a5d5c51b
      libsw {
        library myspace
        uuid 3462a6e0-655a-11e4-8b67-0002a5d5c51b
      }
      libhw {
        library offload
        uuid  c7a84e61-eebe-4fcc-bc53-efcb841b4625
      }
  }
visualizer {#
    library visualizer
    uuid d069d9e0-8329-11df-9168-0002a5d5c51b
  }
      dax {
        library dax
        uuid 9d4921da-8225-4f29-aefa-6e6f69726861
      }
```

It doesn't give the indentation you want. Is that a deal breaker?

Comment: I'll try this in posix shell in Android. Is there any way to keep the indentation? This is why I use sed, which is not my preferred method.